# Can't upgrade firebase to Pay as you go plan by visa card

Tags: firebase

I'm from Vietnam, I want to upgrade firebase to Pay as you go plan, I've used the visa card which was used to purchase  google play accounts, but i couldn't, .
Why is that?

**UPDATE:**
[image]

all information is correctly filled

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your original post with the error you are receiving.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use a Visa prepaid card, which according to Google, is not a valid form of payment (line two in the below picture). You will need to use a valid credit card or debit card so Google can bill you monthly. You can find more information about supported payment methods from [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#supported_payment_methods).

[image: Unsupported payment methods]

[Unsupported payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#unsupported_payment_methods)